# Spring Integration-Load test the tcp server using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, spring-integration

I am trying to load test my tcp server which is created using spring integration using JMeter. I am able to establish the connection with the server using TcpSampler in JMeter, but the server is unable to receive the text sent.

Below are my logs

```html
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Test will stop abruptly on error
INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
INFO o.a.j.p.t.s.TCPClientImpl: Using platform default charset:UTF-8
```

TcpServer accepts ByteArrayCrLfSerializer

In Jmeter, what should be EOL byte value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a JSR223 Pre-Processor under your sampler with following code:

> vars.put("LF",URLDecoder.decode("%0A", "ASCII"));
>       vars.put("CR",URLDecoder.decode("%0D", "ASCII"));

Then append to your TCP message:

> ${CR}${LF}

Comment: I have tried this, but couldn't resolve.I am getting warnings for JSR223 Pre-Processor: llegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/4.0/libexec/lib/groovy-all-2.4.13.jar) to field java.net.URLDecoder.dfltEncName
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass

Comment: I tried with BeanShellPreProcessor, but getting 
Response message: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0

Comment: I have fixed the issue. it is because of ASCII code mistake. CR -> 0D, LF ->OA

Comment: vars.put("LF",URLDecoder.decode("%0A", "ASCII")); vars.put("CR",URLDecoder.decode("%0D", "ASCII"));